# Obtaining error on an actual Android device but it works perfectly in emulator

Tags: android

This is my code and it works perfectly in an emulator but some reason, this problem occurred in on a real device.

> Error in http connectionjava.net.UnknownHostException: my.url.com

```
try{

 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost http = new HttpPost("http://my_url.com/folder/login.php");
 http.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 is = entity.getContent();
 }catch(Exception e){
     Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
}
```

Comment: And I assume your my_url points to some local IP like 192.168...., Am I Correct ?

Comment: Do you have gprs enabled or wifi enabled? Is that URL a public URL?

Comment: well where is this my_url.com is hosted ? Real device may not have access to it, if it is not available in internet.

Comment: I think the url is relevant here. You should post it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code seems good
can you please check you are not missing to grant to internet access for your device
permission set in your **Android manifest:**
add the following permission that will help you charm...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: If this permission is not available, it will not work in Emulator also!!

Comment: thanks depeak sharma i checked my android manifiest there was no line i have mentioned as you told me to do.i put that code now i am able to post data to server from emulater and real device too

Comment: @user3804557 Are you sure it worked on a emulator? If yes, I have learnt a new thing.

Comment: What a funny situation here... his code works fine without internet permission. :D

Comment: @PankajKumar Is that possible? I am puzzled here.

Comment: @LazyNinja No not possible. You can try it also :)

Answer (score 1):

`Error in http connectionjava.net.UnknownHostException` occurs

- if the URL is not recognizable 
  or
- if the client does not have sufficient permissions to call the URL 
  or
- if the client is restricted via firewall to access the url.

To avoid it, check the following:

1. Check if my.url.com is public URL available for internet use.
2. Check if internet(GPRS) and/or wi-fi connection available in the mobile phone.
3. If it is a private URL, then ensure that your mobile is connected to the private network same as the emulator via wi-fi.